# CMake - unwanted rebuilding when there are no changes

Tags: makefile, cmake, compilation, external-project

I am working on a project that uses ExternalProject, with BUILD_IN_SOURCE=TRUE, and the entire project (all of the sources and targets) are rebuilt every time, as though make is unable to see that the files already exist. My implementation looks like this:

```
# Need to explicitly enable ExternalProject functionality
include(ExternalProject)

# Download or update library as an external project
ExternalProject_Add(project_bdsg
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/vgteam/libbdsg-easy.git
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        UPDATE_DISCONNECTED True
        BUILD_ALWAYS False
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE True
        INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/bdsg/
        INSTALL_COMMAND make INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/bdsg/ install
        )

# Define INSTALL_DIR as the install directory for external library
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_bdsg INSTALL_DIR)

# Create new library for external project (so it can be linked with main library)
add_library(bdsg STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET bdsg
        PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libbdsg.a)

add_library(divsufsort STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET divsufsort
        PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libdivsufsort64.a)

add_library(libhandlegraph STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libhandlegraph
        PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libhandlegraph.a)

add_library(libsdsl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libsdsl
        PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libsdsl.a)

# Define library as dependent on the downloaded project
add_dependencies(bdsg
        project_bdsg
        libsdsl
        libhandlegraph
        divsufsort)

# Define main library as dependent on the downloaded project (transitively)
add_dependencies(Bluntifier bdsg)

# Ensure that main library has access to primary dependencies' and secondary dependencies' headers
include_directories(external/bdsg/include/)
```

and I have targets defined like this:

```
    add_executable(${FILENAME_PREFIX} src/test/${FILENAME_PREFIX}.cpp)
    set_property(TARGET ${FILENAME_PREFIX} PROPERTY INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
    target_link_libraries(${FILENAME_PREFIX}
            Bluntifier
            Threads::Threads
            bdsg
            divsufsort
            libhandlegraph
            libsdsl)
```

Running make with some debugging output gives me messages like this:

```
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/build'.
 File 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/build' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'Bluntifier.a'.
    Considering target file 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/link.txt'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/link.txt'.
    No need to remake target 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/link.txt'.
    Considering target file 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/src/adjacency_components.cpp.o'.
     File 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/src/adjacency_components.cpp.o' does not exist.
      Considering target file '../src/adjacency_components.cpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../src/adjacency_components.cpp'.
      No need to remake target '../src/adjacency_components.cpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/bdsg/internal/packed_structs.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/bdsg/internal/packed_structs.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/bdsg/internal/packed_structs.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/expanding_overlay_graph.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/expanding_overlay_graph.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/expanding_overlay_graph.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/handle_graph.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/handle_graph.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/handle_graph.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/iteratee.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/iteratee.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/iteratee.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/types.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/types.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/types.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/util.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/util.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/handlegraph/util.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/bits.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/bits.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/bits.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/config.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/config.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/config.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/int_vector.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/int_vector.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/int_vector.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/int_vector_buffer.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/int_vector_buffer.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/int_vector_buffer.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/io.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/io.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/io.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/iterators.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/iterators.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/iterators.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/memory_management.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/memory_management.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/memory_management.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/ram_filebuf.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/ram_filebuf.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/ram_filebuf.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/ram_fs.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/ram_fs.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/ram_fs.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/sdsl_concepts.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/sdsl_concepts.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/sdsl_concepts.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/sfstream.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/sfstream.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/sfstream.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/structure_tree.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/structure_tree.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/structure_tree.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/uintx_t.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/uintx_t.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/uintx_t.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/util.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/util.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../external/bdsg/include/sdsl/util.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../inc/adjacency_components.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../inc/adjacency_components.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../inc/adjacency_components.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../inc/subtractive_graph.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../inc/subtractive_graph.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../inc/subtractive_graph.hpp'.
      Considering target file '../inc/utility.hpp'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file '../inc/utility.hpp'.
      No need to remake target '../inc/utility.hpp'.
      Pruning file '../src/adjacency_components.cpp'.
      Pruning file 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/flags.make'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/src/adjacency_components.cpp.o'.
    Must remake target 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/src/adjacency_components.cpp.o'.
[ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/src/adjacency_components.cpp.o
    Successfully remade target file 'CMakeFiles/Bluntifier.dir/src/adjacency_components.cpp.o'.
```

where `adjacency_components.cpp` is one of several source files that are rebuilt every time I run make. Why does make conclude that it needs to rebuild these targets?

Comment: The code provided is definitely **insufficient**. According to the log, you have files being rebuilt as part of `Bluntifier` target. But the portion of `CMakeLists.txt` you show doesn't contain creation of this target.

Answer (score 0):

After looking further up in my debug output, it became apparent that cmake was tracking file timestamps from the downloaded content of the ExternalProject. Since it was redownloading every time I recompiled, there was always a fresh timestamp that cause all dependees to appear out of date in relative terms, which then triggered recompiling everything. To stop this temporarily, while developing, it is sufficient to add the following lines:

```
        DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
```

to the ExternalProject arguments. Ideally this would be tied to a flag that the developer could invoke so that this is not the default behavior.